# Dynamic array changing memory address locations

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I'm having a slight issue and not quite understanding the syntax for what I'm wanting to do. See below:

```
float* ParticleSystem::GetMinLifeTime()
{
    return &minLifeTime;
}
```

I'm wanting to declare a dynamic array and then change the value of element 0 to point to the minLifeTime memory location. MY attempt so far has been:

```
float* lifeTimeNumbers = new float[LIFETIME_STRINGS_SIZE];


lifeTimeNumbers[0] = *activeParticleSystem->GetMinLifeTime();
```

My understanding though is that I'm dereferencing the values when adding them to the array. This isn't what I'm wanting. I'm really wanting to change the memory location of lifeTimeNumbers[0] to the memory location returned by GetMinLifeTime(). Can I do such a thing?

Cheers

Comment: You need to understand how the allocations you make, are put in memory. The allocation line in your code, will create one sequential chunk of memory which holds floats. The memory address of float value with index `i` will be (sizeof float) less than that with index `i + 1`. **You cannot change that**. So, either you want your array to be of pointers, but then each reference will need to dereference that pointer which affects speed, or perhaps you want two variables. One being a pointer to a float, another being an array of floats. It's easier to answer if you elaborate on what you want.

Comment: I basically wanted an array of pointers which I misunderstood about how to declare. I've managed to fix this issue now but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't change the address of [0] of the array as the array is basically ONE area of memory and not a number not individual pointers.

Your 'isssue' could be done using a **.. then you could have [0] store a pointer to the value

Answer (score 1):

Your question is mostly about how to fix the problems with an approach Y to achieving X.

Where approach Y is really meaningless (this is known as an **XY-problem**).

Instead of focusing on Y, do X directly:

```
#include <vector>

double ParticleSystem::minLifeTime() const
{
    return minLifeTime_;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> lifeTimeNumbers;

    ParticleSystem activeParticleSystem = ...;
    lifeTimeNumbers.push_back( activeParticleSystem.minLifeTime() );
}
```

Comment: I need the memory addresses specifically as I need changes to the value to also be changed in the particle effect. I'm not sure your approach would work.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm really wanting to change the memory location of lifeTimeNumbers[0] to the memory location returned by GetMinLifeTime()

All you need to do is this:

```
float *lifeTimeNumbers = activeParticleSystem->GetMinLifetime();
```

Now you have a pointer which points to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an array of pointers to floats rather than an array of floats. To achieve that you have to declare the array like this

```
float** lifeTimeNumbers = new float*[LIFETIME_STRINGS_SIZE];
lifeTimeNumbers[0] = activeParticleSystem->GetMinLifeTime();
```

but why not just using a vector container like this

```
std::vector<float*> vec;
vec.push_back(activeParticleSystem->GetMinLifeTime());
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough of a reason either way to be honest.